# Android studio interface - Expand/Collapse code not visible

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After exiting full screen mode on android studio the interface did not show up correctly, I fixed some of them by myself, I just cant seem to fix the last one.

The + and - to expand or collapse functions/methods is not showing, I can still do this by going to the toolbar > code > folding > Expand/Collapse.

I did try restarting android studio (few times), tried searching on google and looked into android studio's settings.

- Android studio 2.2.2
- Windows 10 home
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

Answer (score 0):

I Clicked File>Repair IDE and it restored my Expand/Collapse arrows.